# C++23 std::stacktrace in segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stack-trace

I have noticed that c++23 has a `std::stacktrace`. Sometimes our unit tests are crashing on jenkins in a segfault but we cannot reproduce the issue locally. That's why I'd like to use `std::stacktrace`.

MSVC 17 has a good working `std::stacktrace`, that why we are starting with msvc. But later it should be used on linux as well.

First something to clarify:

1. I know that catching a segfault is not that trivial. Many things (like `malloc()` are not allowed in a signal handler). While some issues like malloc can be easily avoiding by providing a statically allocated memory pool allocator other things like `printf()` and `std::cerr` can not be avoiding easily. However this is only in test code. The produtive code will not get messed up
2. we are using /Ehsc so no windows speific SEH Excecption handling is possible

However my signal handler is not called. This is my setup

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

#include <csignal>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stacktrace>


static void SignalHandler(int signal);
static void SignalHandler(int signal)
{
  const std::stacktrace stacktrace = std::stacktrace::current(0, 10);
  std::cerr << "Caught Signal " << signal <<": " << stacktrace << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && defined(_DEBUG)
  _set_error_mode(_OUT_TO_STDERR);
  _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
#endif

  [[maybe_unused]] auto prevSignalHandlerSegfault = std::signal(SIGSEGV, SignalHandler);
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  int res = RUN_ALL_TESTS();
  return res;
}
```

Inside my Test I'm simply calling to trigger a segfault

```
TEST(Foo,Bar)
{
  int* pFoo = nullptr;
  *pFoo = 10;
}
```

I have set a breakpoint in `SignalHandler()` but I'm never getting into this function.
The console only shows the obvious

```
unknown file: error: SEH exception with code 0xc0000005 thrown in the test body.
```

Am I missing something? Can I not catch segfaults by overwriting the signal handlers?

Comment: AFAIK the only way on Windows is still to use SEH - It just ignores SIGSEV signals (since it uses a different mechanism)

Comment: SEH is one of the more common symptoms of dereferencing an invalid or null pointer under windows.  One problem with trying to intercept an error associated with undefined behaviour (whether it results in a SIGSEGV signal, a SEH, or something else) is that the symptom may occur some considerable time after the cause, in unrelated code - so, at best, the stack trace you get will be where a symptom of the error is detected (e.g. by the OS) and that may have no actual relationship to code that is the root cause.

Comment: Do not make this over complicated. Test are crashing only on Jenkins. This means you have UB which can be detected by other tools. Just try run test with address sanitizer enabled (or other sanitizers). This is cheep to do and should help you find this problem in 99% of cases. Note this tool is currently supported by all major compilers: clang, gcc and MSVC. When problem appear you will get nice detailed technical report what is tech problem without changing even single line of code.

Comment: Have you considered configuring the OS to collect a dump when the app under test crashes (either full or mini-dump) and then loading the dump into the windows debugger?

Comment: thx for your answers. I haved worked with backtrace on linux which gave pretty good results in most cases. I thought using `std::stacktrace` would make things more portable. If SEH is the only working way I'll go with this. @MarekR Sanitisers are on my list as well, however I'll have to build all 3rd parties again with the proper sanitiser flags (also sanitisers only work well with Debug builds, we are testing release builds) :)

Comment: @RichardCritten How can I collect a os dump. Do you have something specific in mind?

Comment: [Collecting User-Mode Dumps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps)

Comment: @JHeni I didn't rebuild third party libraries and I was using address sanitizer with no problems on clang. Only MSVC has this institutionalization for `std::vector` which breaks compatibility so I had to disable this feature (had to add macors `_DISABLE_STRING_ANNOTATION` `_DISABLE_VECTOR_ANNOTATION`).